# how to hide message when option changes in drop down menu

Tags: jquery

Hi Below I have piece of code where it displays a message stored in another php page using jquery and a html div tag known as `'targetdiv`:

```
 function submitform() {    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updatestudentsession.php",
data: { 
    Idcurrent:  $('#currentid').val(),
    addtextarea:   $('#studentadd').val()
},
        dataType:'json',  //get response as json
        success: function(result){
                    if(result.errorflag){

       //do your stuff on getting error message
      var newHtml="<span style='color: red'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
      $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);  //i am displaying the error msg here

    }else{
       //you got success message

       var newHtml="<span style='color: green'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
            $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);

    $('#targetdiv').show();
        }
    }
  });        
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is that if the user has selected from a drop down menu after that message has appeared, I want it to hide the message. The problem is that when I try to do this, the message does not appear even if I submit the form it does not show the message. My question is how am I suppose to hide the message in the `#targetdiv` tag when option changes but still be able to show the message after the user has submitted the form?

Below is what I tried to do:

```
     $(document).ready( function(){

        $('#sessionsDrop').change( function(){

            $('#targetdiv').hide();
            var search_val = $(this).val();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Hi you can do like this
     $(document).ready( function(){

    $('#sessionsDrop').change( function(){

        $('#targetdiv').hide();

        var search_val = $("#targetdiv>span").text();


     });

   });
```

Comment: hi while submitting form only u r appending span in div(targetdiv).so you can't get that span value in document ready function.

Comment: i couldn't understand ur last comment.

Comment: Sorry it is not working. my submit button is messed up now for some strange reason. This is gonna take some time for me to fix. I will let you know when I sort submit button out and test it again.

Comment: Hi, right I tested your code but it just did not display the message at all after submit. Can you remember what the other answer was as it was deleted, it was using document.on I think, or have you got another solution?